# p value in the emmeans contrast

Tags: gam, emmeans

I am sorry if this question doesn't make too much sense, but I am trying to make a post hoc analysis with my gam selected models. It's normal that my contrast doesn't have any significant p-value?
I was expecting to find which level of my factor was selected in the interaction.
OBS: I have a data set of 169 samples and I am trying to understand which environmental feature (depth, chlorophyll, bottom type, and SST)is more relevant for the CPUE (catch per unit effort). My only categorical variable is the Bottom Type with 13 levels.

```
 dredge(res)
Global model call: gam(formula = nCPUE ~ s(Depth) + s(Chlorophyll) + BottomType + 
    s(SST), data = morio)
---
Model selection table 
      (Int) BtT s(Chl)    s(Dpt)   s(SST) df   logLik  AICc delta weight
4  -0.62310   +  1.597                    15 -304.318 641.8  0.00  0.821
10 18.10000   +                  -0.70940 15 -306.983 647.1  5.33  0.057
3  -0.16020      1.939                     3 -320.855 647.9  6.08  0.039
8  -0.61760   +  1.479 0.0001209          16 -306.497 648.6  6.80  0.027
2  -0.29430   +                           14 -308.959 648.6  6.87  0.026
12  4.10300   +  1.373           -0.18050 16 -306.995 649.6  7.80  0.017
14 17.05000   +        0.0001351 -0.67000 16 -308.616 652.8 11.04  0.003
6  -0.33730   +        0.0002019          15 -310.039 653.2 11.44  0.003
7  -0.08551      1.753 0.0002077           4 -322.626 653.5 11.72  0.002
11  1.19800      1.936           -0.05251  4 -322.824 653.9 12.12  0.002
16  5.40200   +  1.168 0.0001235 -0.22980 17 -308.923 655.9 14.13  0.001
1   0.34150                                2 -326.765 657.6 15.83  0.000
9  17.61000                      -0.66810  3 -325.910 658.0 16.19  0.000
15  2.63300      1.689 0.0001938 -0.10460  5 -324.395 659.2 17.38  0.000
5   0.37710            0.0002781           3 -326.857 659.9 18.09  0.000
13 15.94000            0.0002114 -0.60260  4 -326.783 661.8 20.04  0.000
Models ranked by AICc(x)


post.hoc = emmeans(res, specs = ~ BottomType|Chlorophyll)
moriotukey<-contrast(post.hoc, method = "pairwise")
summary(moriotukey)
 contrast                                                                   estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (CA+RB 0.258698224852071)                            -2.3155 1.101 Inf -2.103  0.6619 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                         -0.9394 1.729 Inf -0.543  1.0000 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (CA+RE 0.258698224852071)                            -0.1050 1.966 Inf -0.053  1.0000 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071)                   -3.9677 1.742 Inf -2.277  0.5338 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071)                -4.2754 1.772 Inf -2.413  0.4346 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - MI 0.258698224852071                                 -0.4388 1.000 Inf -0.439  1.0000 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)                             0.0124 1.731 Inf  0.007  1.0000 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - RB 0.258698224852071                                 -0.6403 0.798 Inf -0.803  0.9999 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                            -1.9403 1.200 Inf -1.616  0.9253 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                         -4.0034 1.804 Inf -2.220  0.5767 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - RE 0.258698224852071                                 -0.2632 0.795 Inf -0.331  1.0000 
 CA 0.258698224852071 - SS 0.258698224852071                                 -3.4633 1.341 Inf -2.583  0.3205 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                     1.3761 1.734 Inf  0.794  0.9999 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE 0.258698224852071)                        2.2105 1.908 Inf  1.158  0.9950 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071)              -1.6521 1.731 Inf -0.954  0.9992 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071)           -1.9599 1.748 Inf -1.121  0.9963 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - MI 0.258698224852071                             1.8767 1.011 Inf  1.856  0.8210 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)                        2.3279 1.733 Inf  1.344  0.9818 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                             1.6753 0.809 Inf  2.070  0.6857 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                        0.3752 1.184 Inf  0.317  1.0000 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                    -1.6879 1.771 Inf -0.953  0.9992 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                             2.0523 0.797 Inf  2.574  0.3260 
 (CA+RB 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                            -1.1478 1.353 Inf -0.848  0.9998 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE 0.258698224852071)                     0.8344 2.381 Inf  0.351  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071)           -3.0282 2.198 Inf -1.378  0.9776 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071)        -3.3359 2.222 Inf -1.502  0.9562 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - MI 0.258698224852071                          0.5007 1.671 Inf  0.300  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)                     0.9518 2.189 Inf  0.435  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                          0.2992 1.558 Inf  0.192  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                    -1.0009 1.799 Inf -0.556  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                 -3.0639 2.247 Inf -1.363  0.9795 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                          0.6763 1.557 Inf  0.434  1.0000 
 (CA+RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                         -2.5239 1.895 Inf -1.332  0.9831 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071)              -3.8626 2.302 Inf -1.678  0.9039 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071)           -4.1704 2.254 Inf -1.850  0.8242 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - MI 0.258698224852071                            -0.3338 1.929 Inf -0.173  1.0000 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)                        0.1174 2.363 Inf  0.050  1.0000 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                            -0.5352 1.824 Inf -0.293  1.0000 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                       -1.8353 1.927 Inf -0.953  0.9992 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                    -3.8984 2.227 Inf -1.750  0.8737 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                            -0.1582 1.793 Inf -0.088  1.0000 
 (CA+RE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                            -3.3583 2.143 Inf -1.567  0.9400 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071)  -0.3077 2.193 Inf -0.140  1.0000 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - MI 0.258698224852071                    3.5289 1.689 Inf  2.089  0.6718 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)               3.9801 2.195 Inf  1.813  0.8438 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                    3.3274 1.575 Inf  2.113  0.6551 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)               2.0273 1.786 Inf  1.135  0.9959 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)           -0.0357 2.207 Inf -0.016  1.0000 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                    3.7045 1.566 Inf  2.366  0.4682 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                    0.5043 1.915 Inf  0.263  1.0000 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - MI 0.258698224852071                 3.8366 1.722 Inf  2.228  0.5706 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)            4.2878 2.215 Inf  1.936  0.7743 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                 3.6351 1.609 Inf  2.259  0.5472 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)            2.3351 1.794 Inf  1.301  0.9861 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)         0.2720 2.190 Inf  0.124  1.0000 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                 4.0122 1.594 Inf  2.517  0.3626 
 (CA+RE+MI+RB+SS+TE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                 0.8121 1.948 Inf  0.417  1.0000 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - (MI+RE 0.258698224852071)                             0.4512 1.674 Inf  0.269  1.0000 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - RB 0.258698224852071                                 -0.2015 0.662 Inf -0.304  1.0000 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                            -1.5015 1.121 Inf -1.339  0.9823 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                         -3.5646 1.757 Inf -2.029  0.7138 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - RE 0.258698224852071                                  0.1756 0.660 Inf  0.266  1.0000 
 MI 0.258698224852071 - SS 0.258698224852071                                 -3.0245 1.264 Inf -2.392  0.4494 
 (MI+RE 0.258698224852071) - RB 0.258698224852071                            -0.6527 1.563 Inf -0.418  1.0000 
 (MI+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                       -1.9527 1.794 Inf -1.088  0.9972 
 (MI+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                    -4.0158 2.238 Inf -1.795  0.8529 
 (MI+RE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                            -0.2756 1.560 Inf -0.177  1.0000 
 (MI+RE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                            -3.4757 1.899 Inf -1.830  0.8348 
 RB 0.258698224852071 - (RB+RE 0.258698224852071)                            -1.3001 0.942 Inf -1.380  0.9774 
 RB 0.258698224852071 - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                         -3.3631 1.645 Inf -2.044  0.7032 
 RB 0.258698224852071 - RE 0.258698224852071                                  0.3771 0.266 Inf  1.418  0.9719 
 RB 0.258698224852071 - SS 0.258698224852071                                 -2.8231 1.112 Inf -2.539  0.3484 
 (RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071)                    -2.0631 1.811 Inf -1.139  0.9957 
 (RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                             1.6771 0.927 Inf  1.809  0.8455 
 (RB+RE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                            -1.5230 1.440 Inf -1.058  0.9979 
 (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071) - RE 0.258698224852071                          3.7402 1.626 Inf  2.301  0.5163 
 (RB+SS+RE 0.258698224852071) - SS 0.258698224852071                          0.5401 1.981 Inf  0.273  1.0000 
 RE 0.258698224852071 - SS 0.258698224852071                                 -3.2001 1.113 Inf -2.875  0.1690 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 13 estimates
```

[plot(post.hoc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5FxH.png)

Comment: You can make the output a lot less messy by leaving out Chlorophyll, since it is being held fixed at only one value (its mean). Another factor is that you are doing 13*12/2=78 comparisons. That is a lot of tests, and the P values are adjusted to protect against making ANY type I errors. That makes them pretty conservative. Consider whether it is really important to compare everything with everything else.

Comment: Thank you @RussLenth I tested it even without chlorophyll and still, there is no significance for any comparison between any of the levels ... Could you tell me if when we have unique values per line within the variable, when we compare, the analysis always uses the average? I noticed this when I analyzed other species, using other selected variables, such as depth and temperature for example...Another problem is that my categorical variable has many levels and I can't group it any other way

Comment: Please read the "basics" vignette, and perhaps others too. Those will answer many of your questions.